# Trying to get link_to for a thumbnail to work in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Been trying to make my bootstrap thumbnail clickable so that it will open up and show the post without needing to click on a button. Having trouble searching for a solution.

Current code:

```
<div class = "row">
  <% @companies.each do |company| %>

    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <%= link_to "none", company %>
        <img src="<%= company.pic %>">
          <div class="caption">
            <h3><%= company.title %></h3>
            <p><%= company.description.first(60) %></p>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>

</div>
```

I tried  <%= link_to "none", company %> and it just added another link on top of my picture. Would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) with a block

```
<%= link_to company do %>
  <img src="<%= company.pic %>">
<% end %>
```

From docs:

> You can use a block as well if your link target is hard to fit into the name parameter. ERB example:

```
<%= link_to(@profile) do %>
  <strong><%= @profile.name %></strong> -- <span>Check it out!</span>
<% end %>
# => <a href="/profiles/1">
       <strong>David</strong> -- <span>Check it out!</span>
     </a>
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass it in a block:

```
<%= link_to company do %>
   <img src="<%= company.pic %>">
<% end %>
```

You can pass any HTML within a link_to function, but you need to add the 'do' for it to process it within a block (or {}).

Answer (score 0):

I would try to avoid mixing ERB and HTML, therefore I would prefer to use `link_to` with `image_tag` like this:

```
<%= link_to(company) do %>
  <%= image_tag(company.pic) %>
  <div class="caption">
    <h3><%= company.title %></h3>
    <p><%= company.description.truncate(60) %></p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```